# Method returning array shorthand property. Which PHP version?

Tags: php, syntax, version

At some point, I'm not sure when, the following shorthand property became available to reference an element in an array that became returned by a method:

```
echo $someObject->SomeMethod()['SomeElement'];
```

Where you append the element name after the method parentheses but before the semi-colon. What PHP version was this made available in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function array deferencing was available from PHP 5.4.0

See [**`here`**](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Comment: Ahh, is that the name for it. Thank you.